# How to convert the data in the rows to columns form?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have an employee table with columns like emp_id, headcount, fte, effective_date, status, status_2.

I need to create a report with from date and end date as the input. This will be checked against effective_date.

If the input is from date = 1st Jan 2012 to end date 25th Feb 2013 then result should be shown in following format as shown in image below.

[image]

The numbers 1,0,10,20 indicates the sum of the headcount for the month specified.

e.g. if there are 5 employees with effective date in the month of March then March will have 5 in the column and  then those 5 will be again split on the basis of the status and status_2 columns of the employees.

e.g. out of those 5, 2 might be status A, status_2 A1
3 might be status A, status_2 A2

How do I write a query to get result i such format?

Below is the DDL for employee table.

```
--------------------------------------------------------
--  DDL for Table BI_EMPLOYEE
--------------------------------------------------------

CREATE TABLE "HEADCOUNT_BI"."BI_EMPLOYEE" 
(   
    "EMP_ID" NUMBER(*,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "STATUS" NUMBER(*,0), 
    "STATUS_2" NUMBER(*,0), 
    "FTE" FLOAT(126), 
    "EFFECTIVE_DATE" DATE, 
    "HEADCOUNT" NUMBER(*,0), 
    CONSTRAINT "HEADCOUNT_EMPLOYEE_BI_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("EMP_ID") ENABLE
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should [pivot](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/sql/11g-pivot-097235.html) data. With Oracle 11:

```
SELECT 
   *
FROM   
   ( select 
       status, status_2,to_char(EFFECTIVE_DATE,  'Mon''DD') as EFFECTIVE_DATE,
       sum( HEADCOUNT ) as HEADCOUNT
     from "BI_EMPLOYEE" 
     group by status, status_2,EFFECTIVE_DATE
   )
PIVOT  
   (
    sum(HEADCOUNT) 
    for  EFFECTIVE_DATE in  ( 'Jan''12', 'Feb''12' )
   )
```

Notice that pivot fields list must be a constant.

**Edited, at this time I see that you aggregate by month, not day**:

```
SELECT 
   *
FROM   
   ( select 
       status, status_2,to_char(EFFECTIVE_DATE,  'Mon''YY') as EFFECTIVE_DATE,
       sum( HEADCOUNT ) as HEADCOUNT
     from "BI_EMPLOYEE" 
     group by status, status_2, to_char(EFFECTIVE_DATE,  'Mon''YY') 
   )
PIVOT  
   (
    sum(HEADCOUNT) 
    for  EFFECTIVE_DATE in  ( 'Jan''12', 'Feb''12' )
   )
```

You can learn how to [pivot in Oracle previus versions.](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0%3a%3a%3a%3ap11_question_id:766825833740)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is there any way pivot fields list can be dynamic i.e. I will know the start date and end date  and based on that I will need to created pivot field list.

Comment: There is not a direct way. You can diggin web searchin for dynamic pivot. I suggest to you that 'cook' pivot fields with your language program. What language are you using to retrieve data from Oracle?

Comment: java is the language we are using

Comment: isnt theer is something like we can do for effective_date in (  // some query which gives all months between from date and end date) ?

Comment: Then, when you conpose query in java you should write two queries, first one to get 'fields' ( `select distinct to_char(EFFECTIVE_DATE,  'Mon''YY') as EFFECTIVE_DATE from BI_EMPLOYEE where EFFECTIVE_DATE between ... ` ) and the second one sentence is the pivot sentence. Bye.

Comment: If you don't mind getting the results as XML instead of a regular resultset, then you can use the `pivot xml` clause with the `ANY` keyword: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_10002.htm#CHDFAFIE